# Service get killed, not for memory reason

Tags: android, android-service

When my Activity quits, I registered a pending intent in the alarm, which will start up a NotificationService in 60  seconds. The codes of onCreate() is below:

```
PlayLogSender.getInstance(this).startSend();
```

and startSend():

```
public void startSend(){
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        log("[thread]started");
        int interval=20;
        try{
            //wait for QTRadioService starting in case of this is a APP launch
            Thread.sleep(interval*1000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        log("sleep "+s+"s done");
        while(some condition){
            ......
        }
    }
}.run()
}
```

And when the PlayLogSender's thread finished sleeping, android killed NotificationService; then restart ed it and killed it again. At last NotificationService never got up again. I tried to set "interval" as 15, then everything works fine. So I think it's not because of memory that android kills it.

Could anyone help on this? Why Android kills my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `run()` on a `Thread` won't run it on a separate thread but in the calling thread. To run in separate thread, call `start()`.

Android kills your service if you block the main thread for too long.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your log?probably ANR.

Comment: I should not call run() directly. Thank you anyway.